# Getting Active View in TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am attempting to get the active view controller in the TabBarController given that a user has selected a tab. However, calling:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(String(self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController?.title))
}
```

Is always nil.

How can I get this to note the active view in the tab?

Comment: Are you sure your tabbarcontroller is not nil?

Comment: @NikoYuwono I am using: `self.selectedIndex`, instead. It works

Comment: Are you sure it's not nil because you didn't set a title?  What happens if you just print tabBarController, and then just tabBarController.selectedViewController?